# CLEAR_TOP to the previous activity with extras

Tags: android, android-intent

In my navigation the following sequence of activities can be produced: A,B,C,B,C,B,C, ..., D.
D activity contains an overriden method for the Back-button, which sends user to the A activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` parameter.

Activity A receives a number of necessary extra parameters and my problem is that when I trigger startActivity in D activity with this CLEAR_TOP flag activity A doesn't seem to get any previous extra or even launch onResume method.

Does it mean that CLEAR_TOP actually `recreates` the target activity instead of bringing up the old one ? And, is there any system-natural approach to `restore those extra intent` parameters in activity A when I launch it from activity D.

P.S. Right now the only choice I see is to manually fillin those previous necessary parameters when constructing intent object in D activity. Is it a way to go ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that CLEAR_TOP actually recreates the target activity
>   instead of bringing up the old one ?

When you use `CLEAR_TOP` flag,target Activity `does not recreate`,but when you use a new intent to appear Activity A,you can only get this new intent's extras in Activity A.

> And, is there any system-natural approach to restore those extra
>   intent parameters in activity A when I launch it from activity D?

You can save these extras in file,preferences or global application variables,when you leave Activity A.Or you can declare a static method in Activity A that save these extras in it and you would to invoke it from Activity D,before force to appear Activity A:
Activity A:

```
Public class A extends Activity{
...
public static void saveExtras(){
//save extras in file,preferences,...
}
...
}
```

Activity D:

```
Public class D extends Activity{
...
public void forceActivityA(){
A.saveExtras();
Intent i = new Intent(this,A.class());
...
startActivity(i);
}
...
}
```

**Edit**:
When Activity A appears again,it's `onCreate()` method invokes again and here you can get intent that request it.Then you can get intent's flag and compare it with `67108864`(constant for CLEAR_TOP flag).If it equals to this constant you would to retrieve your data from your storage(file,preferences,...).To create global variables you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/4642069#4642069).

Comment: with this code `Intent i = new Intent(FourthActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActivity(i);` SecondActivity's onCreate gets triggered, so I guess it does recreate the whole activity. Yet I don't see any solution to my problem - what would you recommend to restore those extra parameters ? Should I look into onSaveInstanceState method ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Филюстин please see my edits again.Thanks you for your check mark as answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) says.

If you set both `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), then new parameters will be pushed into [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you've found a solution to this or not, but overriding the onNewIntent(Intent theNewIntent) method for the target activity & calling setIntent(theNewIntent) solved it for me.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    /*
     * This overrides the original intent.
     */      
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: Before the call to super.onNewIntent, the old intent is still accessible and you can capture any needed extras and add them to the new intent.